# test if service exists

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm opening a connection of my database in my ionic application. I want that this connection can be used in all tabs. For that I do a service and try save in them the connection variable.

```
.service('connect', function () {
            var arr = {};
            var connection = new ...
            arr['connection'] = connection;
            }
            return arr;
        })
```

Then, to access to them, I do:

```
connect.connection;
```

Problem: I want to do a new connection just the first time I do a connect.connection. The other ones I want just to get back the variable.

I tried anything like that:

```
if(connect == null){
            var connection = new ...
            arr['connection'] = connection;
}
```

inside my service, but it cannot work.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Angular services are singletons. You can do `arr['connection'] = new ... `, and it will run only once. Btw, `this` is supposed to be used instead of `return ...` in `service` service.

Comment: oh, service are singletons? Really? That will help me! Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's key feature of Angular DI. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Answer (score 1):

Angular JS Services are singleton, there is only one object, but is injected into many places. (objects are passed by reference to a method)

For the documentation please look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).
Here I have example where I have initialized method of service to initialized the db.

```
    .service('DBService', function($q, $http,$window,$cordovaSQLite) {
        return {
            initialize: function(dbname) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise  = deferred.promise;
                var response = {result : '',error : ''};
                try {
                    if ($window.cordova) {
                       //result = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("myapp.db");
                       response.result = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"dbname.db",location: 'default'});
                    } else {
                        // Ionic serve syntax
                       response.result = $window.openDatabase("dbname.db", "1.0", "dbname", -1);
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                } catch (error) {
                    response.error = error;
                    deferred.reject(response);
                }
                promise.success = function(fn) {
                    promise.then(fn);
                    return promise;
                }

                promise.error = function(fn) {
                    promise.then(null, fn);
                    return promise;
                }

                return promise;
            }
        }
    });
```

And in the **controller** You need to call like as follows

```
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      DBService.initialize(db_name)
          .success(function(data) {
             //db object
              $scope.db = data.result;
          }).error(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          });
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could do something like:

```
.service('connect', function () {
            var arr = {};
            var connection = new ...
            arr['connection'] = connection;

            return arr;
        })
```

A service is singleton so this will only be run once.
So when you need to retrieve the connection its something like

```
connect.connection;
```